# Random number for HTTPS MAC

Tags: browser, encryption, random, https

Recently I found that Netscape used quite simple algorithm to generate random number for Message Authentication Code to establish an HTTPS connection (Nestscpe used time, process identification number, and parent-process identification number). So now I wonder what source of seed do modern browsers use to guarantee true randomness?

Comment: In software, there is no such thing as a "true randomness".

Comment: I see true randomness all the time when I do code review ;)

Answer (score 2):

[**This question**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4889/485) and [**this question**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/89/485) over on security.SE have some answers describing sources and the randomness available.